# UIControl subclassed for making drawing tool in iOS slides while drawing for the first time?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios8, drawing, touchesbegan

I am having a problem while using something like a DAScratchPad. I had this problem while drawing a line. The initial point is not moving properly and the below problem occurs when I draw the line for the first time:

[image]

In the above image I was trying to draw a straight line but after touches moved this happened. This also happens everytime after the orientation change.

Kindly help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u get solution to this.. if so, a gist would be helpful :) Thanks

Comment: Issue occurring during orientation was due to wrong scaling of the CGPath or Bezier Path.